# In rails what is the syntax to access records in a column of a join table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, table-relationships

I have:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
    #attr_accessible :lastname, :name
    has_many :together
    has_many :teachers, :through => :together
end
```

```
class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
    #attr_accessible :lastname, :name
    has_many :together
    has_many :students, :through => :together
end
```

```
class Together < ActiveRecord::Base
  #attr_accessible :summary
  belongs_to :student
  belongs_to :teacher
end
```

I wanna do something like:

```
Student.find(1).together.summary
```

I want to access the data in the "summary" column, in the join table...

Comment: Why have you commented out the attr_accessible part? Also, why do you have a summary field in your join table? I know you can do this but don't see why you'd have it here

Comment: I have in my application.rb:   config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = false

Comment: because it a "rich join" acording to lynda.com tutorial.... it has information about the relationship

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just trying to get the children you can do:

```
Student.find(1).teachers
```

If your teachers model has a summary field, you could do something like this:

```
Student.find(1).teachers.first.summary
```

I guess if you have a summary field in the join table and you know the student id you could so this:

```
Together.find_by_student_id(1).summary
```

There's other ways to do this. A few ways to skin a Rails cat.

Comment: the "summary" is a column in the join table, so your second example doesnt work...  but I like the last example! :)

Comment: Yeah didn't think you had that col but thought I'd put it in for good measure. Good luck! S